# Как проверить, подписан ли бот на определённый канал пишущего ему человеку?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Как пошагово сделать так, чтобы чат-бот в телеграме проверял подписку на определенный канал пишущего ему человеку?

Answer (score 0):

Проверка реализуется методом [getChatMember(chat_id, user_id)](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember), где:

```
chat_id - id канала (или группы, супергруппы);
user_id - id пользователя.
```

Если пользователь подписан на канал - метод возвращает объект [ChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmember), содержащий все пользовательские данные. Соответственно, проверяйте пользователя этим методом и если метод не вернул успешный ответ, значит пользователь не подписан на канал.